# Why maven uses difference plugin version to build different project

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have project A and B, use Maven 2.2.1

use it to build A, the result is positive, while user it to build B, it failed.

And I found that it use plugin with different version for the two project.

I don't know why ?? The `pom.xml` in both A and B does not specify the version of plugin.

I just want it will use the same version of plugin to build B project as A's.

Do you have any idea about it ?  Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you didn't defined the version of your plugins.

Usually you should have a kind of [corporate/company pom](https://github.com/khmarbaise/smpp/blob/master/pom.xml) which defines all used plugins with their particular version number. By using such approach you prevent exactly such situations.

The best you can do is to define the used plugins in your pom file via pluginManagement:

```xml
<project...>
  .
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-xyz-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>yyyyy</version>
        </plugin>
        .
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    .
  </build>
  .
</project>
```

If you do this you will get reproducible build results.

Furthermore you shouldn't use [Maven 2.X anymore cause it's defined EoL.](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)